# Add average column to Pivot Table SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

The following is my table t_Vote:

```
| CandidateID | AmbassadorID  | Rate |
|      A      |       P1      |  6   |
|      A      |       P2      |  3   |
|      B      |       P1      |  5   |
|      B      |       P2      |  8   |
```

After doing a Pivot this is my output:

```
|CandidateID | P1 | P2 |
------------------------
|     A      | 6  | 3  |
|     B      | 5  | 8  |
```

What I want to achieve is the following table:

```
|CandidateID | P1 | P2 | Average |
----------------------------------
|     A      | 6  | 3  |   4.5   |
|     B      | 5  | 8  |   6.5   |
```

Here is my query in doing the pivot:

```
SELECT CandidateID, Name, [P1],[P2]
FROM
(
    SELECT Name, AmbassadorID, CandidateID, Rate
    FROM t_Vote INNER JOIN t_Candidate
    ON t_Vote.CandidateID = t_Candidate.ID
) SRC
PIVOT
(
    AVG(Rate)
    FOR AmbassadorID IN ([P1],[P2])
) AS nT
```

P.S.
I removed some of the columns in the question just to avoid confusion.

Comment: Why dont you try putting this in `cte` or `temptable` and add extra column for what you need!

Comment: what do you mean cte?

Comment: SELECT CandidateID, Name, [P1],[P2] ,([P1]+[P2])/2 as Average

Answer (score 1):

You can go for this:

```
 ;With cte as
  (
    SELECT CandidateID, Name, [P1],[P2]
    FROM
    (
      SELECT Name, AmbassadorID, CandidateID, Rate
      FROM t_Vote INNER JOIN t_Candidate
      ON t_Vote.CandidateID = t_Candidate.ID
    ) SRC
   PIVOT
    (
      AVG(Rate)
      FOR AmbassadorID IN ([P1],[P2])
    ) AS nT
  )

 Select CandidateID, Name, [P1],[P2],(([P1]+[P2])/2) as [Avg] from cte
```

You can do the same by using temp table. You can find more about `cte` on: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: So if i have more than 2 AmbassadorID i will also add it manually?  in this query `Select CandidateID, Name, [P1],[P2],(([P1]+[P2])/2) as [Avg] from cte`

Comment: CAST((([P1] + [P2] + [P3])/3) AS FLOAT) AS AVG  I added this, but still doesn't cast as float? why?

Comment: Convert `P1`, `P2`, `P3` column itself in the `cte` to `numeric` or in `float`.